# Calling function by string name in activity

Tags: java, android, reflection

I trying to call a function by names as a string:

```java
Method method = null;
try {
    method = Class.forName("com.lab.android.TabActivity").getMethod(item,String.class);
    method.invoke(this, null);
} catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
    Log.e("DTAG","NoSuchMethodException "+e.getMessage());
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    Log.e("DTAG","ClassNotFoundException "+e.getMessage());
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
    Log.e("DTAG","IllegalAccessException "+e.getMessage());
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
    Log.e("DTAG","InvocationTargetException "+e.getMessage());
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I get an exeptioon:

```
NoSuchMethodException com.lab.android.TabActivity.somesome [class java.lang.String]
```

This is the function in my ativity:

```java
public static void somesome() {
    Log.d("DTAG","Great Success");
}
```

Comment: Well, yeah, you are looking up a method with signature `somesome(String string)` that doesen;t exist while your real method is `somesome()`

Comment: Why do you expect this to work?

Comment: Since all your catch clauses do the same, you don’t need to have four of them, you can write `catch(NoSuchMethodException | ClassNotFoundException | IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException e) { Log.e("DTAG", e.getClass().getSimpleName() + " " +e.getMessage()); e.printStackTrace(); }` In this specific case, you can also resort to the base type of these four exceptions, `catch(ReflectiveOperationException e) { Log.e("DTAG", e.getClass().getSimpleName() + " " +e.getMessage()); e.printStackTrace(); }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your method is static in TabActivity class so you should use `getDeclaredMethod` not `getMethod` and also your method takes 0 parameters so you should pass null as a parameter not `String.class`, also to call the static method your should pass null in invoke not this

```java
Method method = null;
String methodName = "somesome";
try {
    method = Class.forName(TabActivity.class.getName()).getDeclaredMethod(methodName, null);
    method.invoke(null, null);
} catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
    Log.e("DTAG","NoSuchMethodException "+e.getMessage());
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    Log.e("DTAG","ClassNotFoundException "+e.getMessage());
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
    Log.e("DTAG","IllegalAccessException "+e.getMessage());
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
    Log.e("DTAG","InvocationTargetException "+e.getMessage());
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This code will print `Great Success` in the log